# How to export database from MySQL Workbench as a single file (not sql)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created schema with some tables and data in MySQL Workbench.
Now I want to export this schema as a database type file which I will use in my project. I only found files in *C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data* but there are many .ibd files (for each table). I want a single file like .mdf from SQL Server. How do I achieve it?

Comment: I don't know about SQL Server's *.mdf* files but don't export a database using the *.ibd* and *.frm* files, this won't work and probably break stuff.

Comment: if yoiu configure 1 file per table all idbfile actually contain the tables and the have th correct bame, that said you need when you copy files the *+exact** database version and you need much more to copy basically the hole data drectory, so why not dump into a sql file and import it on the other side

Comment: I want a single database file (with data inside) which I will use in my C# application. With SQL Server it was simple but here I am confused.

Comment: Go for a SQL file, don't use the internal RDBMS files. There are GUIs and programs like `mysqldump` to do that for you.